# Checking if javascript replace() is empty

Tags: javascript, string, replace

I've been trying to make a simple bbcode parser, it works very well when the code is right but when there's no code I don't know how to handle it.

Here's my code:

```
function BBCodeHTML(text) {
    //WEBSITE 1
    code = '<iframe width="10" height="10" src="https://www.videoWebsite.com/video/$1"></iframe>';
    text = text.replace(/\[videoTag\](.*?)\[\/videoTag\]/g, code);
    return text;
    //WEBSITE 2
    code = '<iframe width="10" height="10" src="https://www.videoWebsite2.com/video/$1"></iframe>';
    text = text.replace(/\[videoTag2\](.*?)\[\/videoTag2\]/g, code);
    return text;
    [...]
}
```

The thing is, if the user just does *[videoTag][/videoTag]*, the **$1** thing (I don't know how to call it) is empty and the embed is still shown (without any video).

Is there anyway I can check if **$1** is empty and IF IT IS NOT then replace with the embed?

Something like "*if $1 = empty { do nothing } else { embed }*"

I tried searching for answers but **$1** empty etc gives me nothing.

If any mod knows a better title for this question, feel free to edit.

Comment: try `(.+?)` instead of `(.*?)`, `*`-nothing or more, `+`-one or more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex :

```
var r = /\[tag\](?!\[\/tag\])(.*?)\[\/tag\]/g;
```

Let's say whitespaces are considered "empty" :

```
var r = /\[tag\](?! *\[\/tag\])(.*?)\[\/tag\]/g;
```

Usage example :

```
'[tag]  [/tag][/tag][tag]content[/tag]'.replace(r, '<tag>$1</tag>');
// "[tag]  [/tag][/tag]<tag>content</tag>"
```

The regular expression :

```
\[tag\]           "[tag]"
(?! *\[\/tag\])   not followed by zero or more whitespaces and "[/tag]"
(.*?)             any char, zero or more times
\[\/tag\]         "[/tag]"
```

Comment: Perfect, worked like a charm! Thanks for the explanation too!

Comment: @Hizan You could do even better doing this : `.replace(/\[(.*?)\](?! *\[\/\1\])(.*?)\[\/\1\]/g, '<$1>$2</$1>')`. Will match any BB tag :)

Comment: @Hizan I appreciate the comments. Sometimes askers don't give any feedback so, I feel like being blind, this is annoying :/ Keep enjoying :)